# Width for wpf Textblock inline elements

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

Is it possible to give width for a textblock inline element in WPF? I am using Run to add inline elements to text block. I want each run to be of same fixed size.But I couldn't find width property for Run.

For example

```
TextBlock txtblck = new TextBlock();
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "abc" });    
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "def" });
```

I want both the Runs to be of same width. Is it possible? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using Spans instead of Runs? I can't check right now but I think they have a width property.

Comment: Hi MoonBoots89, I tried with span. I am afraid there is no width property for it. Also, I guess text cannot be added at run time.

Comment: I believe that you can add text at run time if you declare the Runs at a higher level (rather than creating them within the TextBlock constructor)

Comment: Yes. We can add text at runtime for a Run. But I was talking about Span. I searched for the properties "Width" and "Text" in a Span. Both seem to be missing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [InlineUIContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.documents.inlineuicontainer(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
TextBlock txtblck = new TextBlock();
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new InlineUIContainer
                    {
                        Child = new TextBlock
                                {
                                    Text = "abc",
                                    Width = 100
                                }
                    });    
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new InlineUIContainer
                    {
                        Child = new TextBlock
                                {
                                    Text = "def",
                                    Width = 100
                                }
                    });
```

Comment: Hi Maxim, thanks for your reply. But in my case, I am in a situation not to use textblocks within textblocks. So Is there any other way through style(may be) to give width?

Comment: No you can't set width for `Run`.